# Most efficient way to return multiple aggregates in a single stored proc?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, aggregate

What is the best or most efficient way to get multiple aggregate result values?

Basically I have an email app and wanted to get all the numbers of messages for each type of folder (inbox, sent, archived, flagged... ) as defined below.

Here is a sample of things I am trying to do in one stored proc call. (where [uid] is the userID)

```
SELECT * FROM Message
Inbox    WHERE [to]    = [uid] 
Unread    WHERE [to]    = [uid] and isread = 0
Flagged    WHERE [to]    = [uid] and isFlagged = 1
Drafts    WHERE [to]    = [uid] and isDraft = 1
Sent Messages    WHERE [from] = [uid]
Archived Messages    WHERE [to]     = [uid] and isArchived = 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

COUNT..CASE is the usual way. For "Sent" though it's bit trickier because it's a different uid filter which requires 2 queries on the Message table

I've used this construct to allow for zero  row for to/from. It avoids an OR and adding a uid filter to each CASE.

Each derived table (can write as a CTE) will return only one row and I've used a MAX on uid to avoid GROUP BY too in case anyone wonders

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(M.Inbox, 0) AS Inbox,
    ISNULL(M.Unread, 0) AS Unread,
    ISNULL(M.Flagged, 0) AS Flagged,
    ISNULL(M.Drafts, 0) AS Drafts,
    ISNULL(S.Sent, 0) AS Sent,
    ISNULL(M.Archived, 0) AS Archived
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS InBox,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN isread = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Unread,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN isFlagged = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Flagged,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN isDraft = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Drafts,
        S.Sent,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN isArchived = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Archived
    FROM
        Message
    WHERE
        [to] = [uid] 
    ) M
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Sent
    FROM Message
    WHERE [from] = [uid]
    ) S ON 1=1
```

Edit:

An aggregate without GROUP BY will always return a result (see SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102)). I forgot that.

I've updated my SQL

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Inbox  bigint
DECLARE @Unread bigint
DECLARE @Flagged bigint
/*
MORE DECLARE STATEMENTS GO HERE
*/

SET @Inbox   = SELECT Count(*) FROM MESSAGE WHERE [to] = [uid] 
SET @Unread  = SELECT Count(*) FROM MESSAGE WHERE [to] = [uid] and isread = 0
SET @Flagged = SELECT Count(*) FROM MESSAGE WHERE [to] = [uid] and isFlagged = 1

/*
MORE SELECT STATEMENTS GO HERE
*/

SELECT
@Inbox   as Inbox,
@Unread  as Unread,
@Flagged as Flagged

/*
MORE @Variables GO HERE
*/
```